# How can I target a specific application server using the HTTP "Host" header (using GoLang)

Tags: python, ssl, https, dns, go

### The question:

Why can't I target a server using it's IP address in the request URL and the hostname as the "Host" header using GoLang?
Why does the same thing work using python? (2.7.6 - urllib2)

### Background:

I'm writing a systems test that will send HTTP requests to several specific application servers that I'm testing and inspect the results for correctness. Each application server has the same function and should return the same response data. These servers are grouped behind load balancers. These load balancers are then resolved by DNS and the traffic is forwarded to the backend servers as appropriate. In order to target each server independently (for the tests) I am using each server's IP address in the URL instead of the usual hostname and I'm setting the "Host" HTTP header to be the hostname that usually goes in the url. This is to make sure the SSL cert
can decode the secure (HTTPS) request.

### Current status:

I already have a python script that sends these test requests. Here's the basic idea of that script:

```
headers = {"Host": "<hostname>"} # this <hostname> is usually what would go in the URL on the next line
request = urllib2.Request('https://<ip-address>/path?query=123', headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
# etc...
```

This code has been working fine for several months now. I've verified that it is indeed targeting the correct servers, based on IP address.

### Goal:

I want to replicate this script in golang to make use of the concurrent capabilities of go. The reason I'm using go is that I'd like to send lots more requests at a time (using goroutines).

### Problem:

Using the same technique as shown above (but in Go) I get the following error:

```
Get https://<ip-address>/path?query=123: x509: cannot validate certificate for <ip-address> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Here's an example of the kind of code I have written:

```
request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://<ip-address>/path?query=123", nil)
request.Header.Set("Host", "<hostname>")

client := &http.Client{}
response, err := client.Do(request)
// etc...
```

Again, why does the python code work while the GoLang code returns an error?

Comment: Not sure why it *does* work on python....

Comment: @Volker - check out Caleb's answer for the reason it works in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> Warning: HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate.

To replicate this behavior in Go see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122718/216488

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the clarification. Works like a charm (albeit an insecure one :).