# Get proxy response body as clean string in golang

Tags: html, go, reverse-proxy

I read this solution for resolve body data from a proxy.
[Golang: how to read response body of ReverseProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535569/golang-how-to-read-response-body-of-reverseproxy?newreg=fa3b3b3679c54b2691b95aeb61823ac6)

But I cannot read the body as a plain string, maybe the encoding is not right or other cryption.

My question is `how to encode or transform the body to readable html string?`

Currently I get:

```
n8�������♠�♠�A��b:J���g>-��ˤ���[���.....
```

#### Code example:

```
 reverseProxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
reverseProxy.ModifyResponse = func (resp *http.Response) (err error) {
                var contentType = resp.Header.Get("Content-Type")

                if strings.HasPrefix(contentType, "text/html") {
                    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) //Read html
                    if err != nil {
                        return  err
                    }
                    err = resp.Body.Close()
                    if err != nil {
                        return err
                    }

                    body := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(b))
                    resp.Body = body
                    resp.ContentLength = int64(len(b))

                    log.Printf(string(b))

                }

                return nil
            }
```

Comment: Looks like the server is lying about the content-type. Is there a content-encoding or transfer-encoding header? What does [DetectContentType](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType) return?

Comment: Note that `strings.HasPrefix(contentType, "text/html")` is the WRONG way to check a content type. Your content type might be `text/htmlolthisisreallybinary`.  Use [`mime.ParseMediaType`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#ParseMediaType) instead.

Comment: Thanks your both.
I know what you mean, @Flimzy but it don't look like the problem. With the ParseMediaType I still get text/html the full content type are text/html; charset=UTF-8
The Proxy behind that are custom php application

Thanks Peter for your help. I get this as detected content type
test content text/html; charset=UTF-8 ts text/html
2021/05/20 10:58:19 detect type application/x-gzip

This should be the reason why I only get unreadable body