# Can't get xml from https with skiping certificate

Tags: go

I've read here [How to do a https request with bad certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122159/golang-how-to-do-a-https-request-with-bad-certificate), but also go give error:

> tls: server's certificate contains an unsupported type of public key:
>   *dsa.PublicKey

Here is my code:

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    response, err := client.Get(httpsUrl)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"payload": body})
```

How to fix that?

Comment: What line is the error refering to? Maybe provide a bit more of the stack trace so we can tell where the panic originates.

Comment: ... but the linked solution initializes the config (`... .TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{ ...`) and you don't, you just assign to the uninitialized config's field, so I assume that's where the panic originates.

Comment: ... try https://play.golang.org/p/TBsVWAQxSZC

Comment: same error invokes

Comment: Then please update your question with the stack trace.

Comment: i'' updated question

Comment: what's on line `C:/Users/LolakovF/go/src/hpapi/routes/reports.go:19`?

Comment: defer response.Body.Close()

Comment: You first need to check for errors, and only if it's `nil` can you touch the `response`.

Comment: Example: https://play.golang.org/p/j9v3-Mm9E93

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178671/discussion-between---and-mkopriva).

Comment: That is, if `client.Get` returns a non-nil `err` then `response` is going to be `nil` and calling `defer response.Body.Close()` on a `nil` response is causing your runtime panic.

Comment: Aside: disabling TLS verification on the DefaultTransport is a *really* bad idea. You should create your own Transport instance.