# Geetting connection reset by peer when trying to authenticate to server

Tags: xml, sockets, go, soap, tcp

I am trying to authenticate myself via a Go client. Here is what i have done so far

```
func main() {
    servAddr := "192.168.7.13:443"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", servAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ResolveTCPAddr failed:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Dial failed:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(postReq))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Write to server failed:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(postReq)

    reply := make([]byte, 1024)
    _, err = conn.Read(reply)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Write to server failed:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("reply from server=", string(reply))

    conn.Close()
}
```

This is the message which i am writing to the connection:

> POST /ManagementServer/ServerCommandService.svc HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   192.xxx.xx.xx Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Authorization: Basic {username:password in base64} Content-Length: 405
>   SOAPAction:"http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSServerCommand/IServerCommandService/Login"
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>         190fc316-6412-41c4-8a9c-d468cc7bee9d

After this, I am expecting to get an authentication token, but instead i am getting a

```
> Write to server failed: read tcp server-ip:port->server-ip:443:
> read: connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrong? 
FYI, I am using the same message in python and with sockets I am able to get the token. Can someone help me do the same in Go lang? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the fact, that your server uses the port `443`, I assume the server expects a TLS connection. To get such a connection, you can use [`tls.Dial`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Dial):

```
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", servAddr, nil) // servAddr not tcpAddr
```

This connection will handle the underlying steps required for the encryption of TLS, like the TLS handshake and allow you to `Write` the bytes you want to send, instead of having to do the encryption yourself.

As you mentioned an error with the certificate validation, using

```
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", servAddr, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
```

will disable this validation. **Be aware that this removes most of the security TLS provides.**

One note, I would suggest you use [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) to send simple HTTP requests. To disable the certificate validation here, you can use

```
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
```

but again, **be aware that this removes most of the security TLS provides.** You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122718/5189673) for more details on disabling this for request send using `net.http`.

Comment: conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "192.168.x.xx:443", nil)
I used this but i am getting `Dial failed: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.x.xx because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`