# https request with client.crt and client.key

Tags: ssl, go, curl, https

I want to send a POST request to https server and get the response. Here is what I am doing in curl and it works well.

`curl --key ./client.key --cert ./client.crt https://test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com:443/attestation/sgx/v2/report -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"key": "value"}'`

This is the code snippet I tried in Go.

```
    url := "https://test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com:443/attestation/sgx/v2/report"
    pair, e := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("client.crt", "client.key")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("LoadX509KeyPair:", e)
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                Certificates: []tls.Certificate{pair},
            },
        }}

    resp, e := client.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBufferString(payload))
```

The program is hanging at the last line, error message is

```
Post: dial tcp connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I feel there is problem in my connection establish code, instead of the server's problem since server works perfectly with curl.

Comment: Can you update your code to show where you're setting the URL your requesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ***never ever ever*** use `InsecureSkipVerify: true` no matter how convenient it may seem.  Instead set something like:

```
tls.Config {
    ServerName: "test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com",
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{pair}
}
```

Second, initializing `http.Transport` - to pass your custom tls.Config - also zeros out all the other default `http.Transport` settings that come with the default `http.Client`.

Some of those zero defaults may force behavior you might not expect.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011355/1218512) on how to restore some of those original defaults.

Comment: Works! I never notice that other fields are affected by assigning the config. Thank you very much!

Comment: curious @J.Z which default field triggered the fix?  TLS handshake timeout?

Comment: It's the proxy one fixed the issue. `Proxy: defaultTransport.Proxy`. I have http_proxy and https_proxy in my environment variable.