# Create HTTPS test server for any client

Tags: go

The server created by [NewTLSServer](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_NewTLSServer) can validate calls for a client that is explicitly created from it:

```
ts := httptest.NewTLSServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, client")
}))
defer ts.Close()

client := ts.Client()
res, err := client.Get(ts.URL)
```

in the line `client := ts.Client()`.

However, I have a production program that I want to set to use `ts.URL` as its host. I am getting

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

errors when I call it.

How can I set `ts` up to authenticate with the client like a normal HTTPS server?

Comment: Either you need to use the correct certificate, or create an insecure connection to your HTTPS Server, a bit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122718/4121573

Comment: @Adonis Yeah, enabling the possibility of `InsecureSkipVerify` getting turned on in our production code is not an option. How would I "use the correct certificate"? That is basically what I'm asking for in my original question.

Comment: Can you clarify your situation? From the question it sounds like you're trying to use use `httptest.NewTLSServer` to serve secure traffic in production.

Comment: @Adrian No, I am definitely not trying to use it in production. I am trying to mock outside production components while testing the real calls of the production component in the project. Since the other production components it communicates with in its calls use HTTPS, I need the mock server from `NewTLSServer` to also use HTTPS.

Comment: The test server is a test server, not a real server. You can make test calls to the test server, and they work (as you've seen). If you want to make *real* TLS calls, you'll have to use a *real* TLS server with a real certificate.

Comment: @Adrian Well, I think the line is a bit blurry here. Obviously they are trying to mock out part of the TLS process or `NewTLSServer` wouldn't exist. I think the job isn't quite done because there is no way to connect to the server without explicitly having access to its code. You can access the test HTTP server without having access to its code. All you need is its URL. It makes since to me that the test HTTPS server should work analogously.

Comment: @ChrisRedford I never tried to generate my own certificate (or use a valid certificate) for the httptest. But, in theory, you might be able to `ts := NewUnstartedServer` instead of `ts := NewTLSServer`. Then, you can tweak the `ts.TLS` which is a `https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config` (you would load another certificate). Then you can `ts.StartTLS()` (since it was a "unstarted server"). Aw, do not forget to `defer ts.Close()`. 

As I said, I never tried, but it might work.

Comment: @JamilloSantos This gets me part of the way there. I tried generating my own `.key` and `.crt` using [this method](https://github.com/denji/golang-tls). However, I then hit the error `cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs http`

Comment: @ChrisRedford Are you generating the certificate to what host? If you generate your certificate, it will be self signed, the same the `NewTLSServer` does.

Comment: @JamilloSantos Got to the bottom of it all in my self-answer. Thanks for your `NewUnstartedServer` contribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Go 1.11, this simply isn't possible to accomplish fully within a `_test.go` program, due to the mechanics of HTTPS.

However, you can do a single certificate signing and generation of `server.crt` and `server.key` files, then reference them in your `_test.go` programs from a local directory indefinitely.

## One-time `.crt` and `.key` generation

This is an abridged, slightly streamlined version of the steps specified in Daksh Shah's Medium article, [How to get HTTPS working on your local development environment in 5 minutes](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec), which will work on a Mac.

In the directory where you want your `server.crt` and `server.key` files, create the two configuration files

### `server.csr.cnf`

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C=US
ST=RandomState
L=RandomCity
O=RandomOrganization
OU=RandomOrganizationUnit
emailAddress=hello@example.com
CN = localhost
```

and

### `v3.ext`

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

Then enter the following commands in that directory

```sh
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048 
# create a passphrase
```

```sh
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem -config server.csr.cnf
# enter passphrase
```

```sh
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config server.csr.cnf
```

```sh
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
# enter passphrase
```

Finally, make your system trust the certificate you used to sign the files by running

```sh
open rootCA.pem
```

This should open the certificate in the Keychain Acces app, where it will be found in the section *Certificates* and named `localhost`. Then to **Always Trust** it

- Press enter to open its window
- Press space to twirl down *Trust*
- Change "When using this certificate:" to *Always Trust*
- Close the window and authenticate your decision

**Note:** I have tried many permutations of `security add-trusted-cert` from the command line and, despite the fact that it adds the cert to the keychain and marks it as "Always Trust", my Go programs just won't trust it. Only the GUI method puts the system in a state that my Go programs will trust the cert.

Any Go programs you run locally using HTTPS will now trust servers you run using `server.crt` and `server.key`.

## Running the server

You can create `*httptest.Server` instances that use these credentials with

```golang
func NewLocalHTTPSTestServer(handler http.Handler) (*httptest.Server, error) {
    ts := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(handler)
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.crt", "server.key")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ts.TLS = &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
    ts.StartTLS()
    return ts, nil
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```golang
func TestLocalHTTPSserver(t *testing.T) {
    ts, err := NewLocalHTTPSTestServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, client")
    }))
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    defer ts.Close()

    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    greeting, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    assert.Equal(t, "Hello, client", string(greeting))
}
```

Comment: The "Keychain Access" part is unfortunate (as in, the entry can be used to compromise security on other parts of your system). It'd be much better for your code to use a blank certificate pool and add only your test CA to it, instead of trying to use the system certificate pool at all. I do this even for production servers (letting the ops folks administering them choose whether to use the system pool or pass in an explicit CA cert set).

Answer (score 0):

The `httptest.Server` creates a self-signed certificate that can be given to a `http.Client` to be able to properly verify the SSL certificate.

Since the certificate is typically bound to the hostname of the server, this is probably the better way to use SSL in testing.

Example here:

1. Setup Test Server:

```golang
    // create a handler
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello World")
    })

    // create a Test Server with SSL
    ts := httptest.NewTLSServer(handler)
```

2a. Quick client, but less flexible:

```golang
    // get the client directly from the test server ts
    cl = ts.Client()
```

2b. Generic client

```golang
    // create a CertPool and add the certificate from ts
    certpool := x509.NewCertPool()
    certpool.AddCert(ts.Certificate())

    // create a tls config with the certPool
    tlsconf := &tls.Config{RootCAs: certpool}
    cl := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsconf}}
```

3. Use the client:

```golang
    // use the client normally
    resp, err := cl.Get(ts.URL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(resp.StatusCode)
    ...
```

If you really *must* use your own certificate, you should be able to create a test server without starting it, set the `tls.Config` and start the server…

```golang
ts := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(h)
ts.TLS = &tls.Config{ /* custom settings here */ }
ts.StartTLS()
```