# curl is able to GET from https; but from golang's http.get(), same https URL does not work

Tags: http, go, curl, https

When I do `curl https://10.184.96.62:3000/status`, server sends back json data. All good.

Using the below golang code, the application prints :

> 2019/05/21 18:29:15 Get https://10.184.96.62:3000/status: x509: cannot
>   validate certificate for 10.184.96.62 because it doesn't contain any
>   IP SANs

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        _, err := http.Get("https://10.184.96.62:3000/status")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have already see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122718/2270041 ?

Comment: How is curl validating the cert?

Comment: @Matteo yes, I have. But that is disabling certificate. I want with certificate.

Comment: @JimB I don't know that. I installed certificate on ` /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` . I am sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: You could try [Step 3 - Supply the Certificates to the Client](https://venilnoronha.io/a-step-by-step-guide-to-mtls-in-go) as described in the article

Comment: @iamthadiyan: have you run `update-ca-certificates`? If it's already included in the root certs then the cert isn't correct. Are you certain you created it with IP SANs?

Comment: @JimB Yes, I have done that. That is the reason why `curl` is succeeding.

Comment: @iamthadiyan, Does `curl -v` give any information on how the cert is accepted? I was thinking it might be accepting an IP in the CN rather than the SAN.

Comment: @JimB Here is the verbose from curl. `$ curl -vvvv https://10.184.96.62:3000/status
*   Trying 10.184.96.62...
* Connected to 10.184.96.62 (10.184.96.62) port 3000 (#0)
* found 150 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 605 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
`

Comment: `*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: 10.184.96.62 (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=AU,ST=State,L=Locaton,O=Org,OU=Unit,CN=10.184.96.62
*        start date: Tue, 21 May 2019 11:13:49 GMT
`

Comment: `*        expire date: Thu, 27 Apr 2119 11:13:49 GMT
*        issuer: C=AU,ST=State,L=Locaton,O=Org,OU=Unit,CN=10.184.96.62
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /status HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.184.96.62:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
`

Comment: So it looks like you have the IP in the CN, which isn’t technically valid but curl seems to allow it. Use a SAN as previously mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the certificate I generated. I used `openssl` to create a self-signed certificate. As I shared, `curl` was able to use it to establish connection with the server. But not the go application.

In some forum I saw a comment that said that getting `openssl` to work in this scenario is tricky. So I used this [go code](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go) to generate the certificate. Using this certificate, go app was also able to make the request with out making any change to the source code I shared in my question.

Hope this helps some one in need.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that the error message indicates is specific to the combination of HTTPS with IP addresses: usually a SSL certificate uses the hostname to check the authenticity of the server. In your case there is no hostname, but a IP address instead. There are two possible solutions to your problem:

1. Use a hostname instead of the IP address and put that hostname into your certificate.
2. Put the IP address you want to use into the `subjectAltNames` ("Subject Alternative Names" - SAN) field of your certificate (see [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6)).

Comment: I created a self-signed certificate using openssl. Since curl is able to use the certificate, I am guessing I did that correctly.