# How can I fix x509: “Tom Akehurst” certificate is not trusted?

Tags: go, ssl-certificate, wiremock

I'm trying to use [testcontainers-go](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/blob/main/docs/examples/cockroachdb.md) with HTTPS mode enabled in tests:

```
req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "wiremock/wiremock",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"8080/tcp", "8443/tcp"},
        Cmd: []string{"--https-port", "8443", "--verbose"},
    }
uri := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s:%s", hostIP, mappedPort.Port())
# see
# https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/blob/main/docs/examples/cockroachdb.md
# https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker#start-a-wiremock-container-with-wiremock-arguments
```

together with [walkerus/go-wiremock](https://github.com/walkerus/go-wiremock) (WireMock go client) and I'm running into

```
Post "https://localhost:59279/foo": x509: “Tom Akehurst” certificate is not trusted
```

I think the reason is `go-wiremock`converts `wiremock.Post(wiremock.URLPathEqualTo` into a direct http call (i.e., it doesn't "[expose](https://github.com/walkerus/go-wiremock/blob/main/client.go#L17)" `http` client):

```
// A Client implements requests to the wiremock server.
type Client struct {
    url string
}
```

so I can't [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122159/how-to-do-a-https-request-with-bad-certificate) it to:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

Is there other workaround?